# Converting a BITMAP structure to a BitmapImage/BitmapSource compatible byte array?

Tags: c#, bitmap, pinvoke

I have a variable containing a `BITMAP` structure. This structure is defined as follows.

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct BITMAP
{
    public Int32 Type;
    public Int32 Width;
    public Int32 Height;
    public Int32 WidthBytes;
    public UInt16 Planes;
    public UInt16 BitsPixel;
    public IntPtr Bits;
}
```

There is nothing wrong with this structure. It gets populated with real data when I try to fetch a bitmap using the GDI `GetObject` API.

The problem arises when I try to convert this into an array of bytes and back again.

Below you see how I convert the structure to an array of bytes. Once again this works fine, and I see data in the array.

```
var bitmap = new BITMAP();
var bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(bitmap);

GetObject(bitmapHandle, bufferSize, out bitmap);

var bytes = new byte[bitmap.WidthBytes * bitmap.Height];
Marshal.Copy(bitmap.Bits, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

DeleteObject(bitmapHandle);

//"bytes" now contains the byte array of pixels.
```

Now, here's where it all goes awry. When I try to convert this given array back to a `BitmapImage` later, I get a `NotSupportedException`.

Here's my code for converting back.

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    stream.Position = 0;

    image.BeginInit();
    image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand;
    image.UriSource = null;
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit(); //it throws the exception here
}

image.Freeze();
```

The exception message is `No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found`.

I have tried looking for a solution online, but with no luck. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I assume it's in the conversion process from a `BITMAP` to a byte array, but I don't know.

**It should be noted that a BitmapSource would be fine as well.**

Comment: Are you sure you want a BitmapImage? or a BitmapSource?

Comment: Yes. I need to display it in a WPF application.

Comment: Yes, precisely. Most WPF apps don't need a BitmapImage. For example, the Image control (used in XAML), does not need a BitmapImage, it just needs an ImageSource (which is the base class, BitmapSource derives from it, and BitmapImage derives from BitmapSource). Hence my question. What do you want to do in the end?

Comment: Aha. Well a BitmapSource would do as well then.

Comment: I see no need for any of this code. Instead of us helping with this deeply flawed code, it would be better for us to solve the real problem. So, what's the real problem? What's you actual goal.

Comment: I depend on a core layer which can only "store" byte arrays as images. In one of my UI layers though, I have a WPF application which both needs to display these images from the core, and insert images to the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're failing when create bitmap data array. You're calculating the array size just multiplying

```
bitmap.WidthBytes * bitmap.Height
```

And that's not an expected source for a BitmapImage because a BitmapImage source needs to be a full bitmap file structure, that's including 54 bytes before pixel data.

more info about Bitmap structure here:
https://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-bmp

Also maybe you need to know that the size of pixel data area is affected by the "padding" some extra bytes located at the end of each Scanline added to complete Int32 blocks to speedup bitmap loading.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a BitmapSource (or an ImageSource), you can use GDI's [CreateBitmapIndirect function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd183486.aspx) and WPF interop's [Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap.aspx) , something like this:

```
  static BitmapSource FromBITMAP(ref BITMAP bmp)
  {
        Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        IntPtr hbitmap = CreateBitmapIndirect(ref bmp);
        if (hbitmap == IntPtr.Zero)
            return null;

        try
        {
            return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbitmap, IntPtr.Zero, rect, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteObject(hbitmap);
        }
  }

  [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern IntPtr CreateBitmapIndirect(ref BITMAP lpbm);

  [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to from a `BITMAP` to a byte array, and then back again to a `BitmapSource` later on. The reason for this is that I have a core which is platform independent, and stores icons as bytes. So when I store the icon, it's as a byte array, and when I read it again (from the UI layer) it needs to be converted to a `BitmapSource`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by from a BITMAP to a byte array to a BitmapSource? The bitmap "Bits" are not enough to create a BitmapSource (or any other bitmap format in fact).

Comment: So in order to convert from a `BITMAP` to a byte array, I would first need to convert it to a `BitmapSource` and then to a byte array?

Comment: What do you mean by "converting a BITMAP to a byte array"? what should contain this byte array?

Comment: The image itself, as described in the question. And this image (in byte array format) must be able to be converted back into a `BitmapSource`.

Comment: A byte array only does not/cannot fully represent an image. You need extra information such as what's found in BITMAP.

Comment: Fair enough - let me put it this way then. A `BITMAP` object is an object in memory, right? Can I somehow take the bitmap (and all of its pixels) and store that into a byte array?

Comment: Are you trying to say you just need the reverse function `static BITMAP ToBITMAP(BitmapSource bmp)`?

Comment: No. I want to have one function which takes a `BITMAP` and outputs a byte array, and another function which takes a byte array and outputs a `BitmapSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong here. BITMAP is not an object, and the code that claims to be getting byte array with pixels is just incorrect, according to GetObject API documentation:

> If hgdiobj is a handle to a bitmap created by calling CreateDIBSection, and the specified buffer is large enough, the GetObject function returns a DIBSECTION structure. In addition, the bmBits member of the BITMAP structure contained within the DIBSECTION will contain a pointer to the bitmap's bit values. If hgdiobj is a handle to a bitmap created by any other means, GetObject returns only the width, height, and color format information of the bitmap. You can obtain the bitmap's bit values by calling the GetDIBits or GetBitmapBits function.

So let start from the beginning. From what I see, your code starts with something called bitmapHandle, which I assume is HBITMAP from somewhere. If that's the case, I think what you really need is one function that takes a HBITMAP and outputs a byte array, and another one the way you described it. Something like this:

```
    private static byte[] GetBitmapData(IntPtr hBitmap)
    {
        var source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, null);
        // You may use Bmp, Jpeg or other encoder of your choice
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        encoder.Save(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }

    private static BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(byte[] data)
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(new MemoryStream(data));
    }
```